# Creating a binary factor form ordinal data in R

Tags: r

I have an ordinal variable that ranges from 1 through 67

```
summary(var)
Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
1.0     4.0     8.0    10.2    15.0    67.0
```

I want to recode it into a binary variable with first level being a score of `1` on the original variable and the second level – all other scores combined.

I assume I have to use `factor()` function, but can't figure out how to aggregate all of the values (excluding `1`) for the second level.

Thanks.

Comment: Try to see if `cut(var, breaks=c(0, 1, 100))` works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the `factor()` function works. You could just use:

```
factor(var == 1, labels=c("other", "one"))
```

The condition will split the data for you, and then `labels` will assign relevant names (otherwise the names will be "FALSE" and "TRUE").